# prove of two sets being equal

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-measure, outer-measure

I am trying to show two sets are equal.

Basically I have a set that is outer measurable, i.e. it satisfies the following:

$m^{*}(A) \geq m^{*}(A \cap E) + m^{*}(A \cap E^c)$ where $E$ is a measurable set and $A$ is an set in $R$. Basically I only consider the real space.

I am asking this question because I want to show that even if $E$ is being translated say by $E + y$ where $y$ is a number, I still could have $E+y$ being Outer-measurable.

My question is this:

how do I show that $A \cap (E+y)^c = ((A-y) \cap E^c) +y$

I want to have that because then, I can say:

$m^{*}(A \cap (E+y)^c) = m^*( ((A-y) \cap E^c) +y ) )$

and hence also the left equal $m^*( ((A-y) \cap E^c) ) )$

because outer-measure is translation invariant.

It is the complement of the $E+y$ and $E$  that is bugging me because for the other part, I was able to show the following two sets are equal:

$A \cap (E+y)$ = $((A-y) \cap E)+ y$

Basically it is the Page 5 in this pdf:
https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~b89089/book/Royden/Royden_3.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just follow the steps they had but with $\not\in$:

$x\in A\cap (E+y)^c\iff \left(x\in A \right)\wedge \left(x\not\in E+y\right),\\
\iff \left(x\in A \right)\wedge \left(x-y\not\in E\right),\\
\iff \left(x-y\in A-y \right)\wedge \left(x-y\not\in E\right)\\
\iff x-y\in (A-y)\cap E^c\\
\iff x\in \left((A-y)\cap E^c\right)+y$

Comment: I think your answer is correct. Merci Beaucoup.

Comment: Je t'en prie :)